# Convert varbinary(max) to image,resize and save it in a folder using c# or vb.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

```
public static BinaryToImage(System.Data.Linq.Binary binaryData)
{
    if (binaryData == null) {
    return null;
    }
    byte[] buffer = binaryData.ToArray();
    System.Drawing.Image newImage = default(System.Drawing.Image);
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    memStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    using (MemoryStream strefgham = new MemoryStream(buffer)) {
       newImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(strefgham);
       return newImage;
    }
}
public static double GetPercent(double width,double height,int originalWidth,int originalHeight)
 {
    if (width <= originalWidth && height <= originalHeight) {
    return 1.0;
    } else 
        {
    double wid = (originalWidth / width);
    double hei = (originalHeight / height);
    return (wid < hei) ? wid : hei;
   }
}


   System.Drawing.Image newImage = default(System.Drawing.Image);
   newImage = BinaryToImage(VarBinaryName.ToArray());
   double perc = GetPercent(newImage.Width, newImage.Height, 300, 300);
   double newWidth = newImage.Width * perc;
   double newHeight = newImage.Height * perc;
   int disWeight = Convert.ToInt32(newWidth);
   int disHeight = Convert.ToInt32(newHeight);
```

So far i am able to convert the varbinary(max) to image, and resized it.But not able to save it in a folder. Is this something to do with Bitmap? Any suggestions?

Comment: Show us your saving code, please. What's happening? Error messages?

Comment: I exactly doesn't know how to save it?

Comment: The [System.Drawing.Image Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) has a `Save` method. Start there.

Answer (score 0):

Hey add this line to save your image in folder

```
if (!Directory.Exists("D:\Test"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory("D:\Test");
        }
newImage.Save(@"D:\Test\New.jpg", origImage.RawFormat);
```

Comment: I got the exception. Its says "A generic error occurred in GDI+."

Comment: What is this origImage ?

Comment: It's a image format if you want `origImage` is your Binaryimage